# Why does the promoted and survivor mem size incremented after once full gc

Tags: java, parallel-processing, garbage-collection

Before the first full gc, the minor gc will promote about 30~120KB objects(the survivor data is about 2-3MB) into tenure gen. But, after a full gc, the promoted data is changed to about 300KB and the survivor data is 3-5MB

And the full garbage collection be triggered will be quick to the first time

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.192-b12) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_192-b12), built on Oct  6 2018 06:46:09 by "java_re" with gcc 7.3.0
Memory: 4k page, physical 8388608k(5921228k free), swap 0k(0k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=260046848 -XX:GCLogFileSize=134217728 -XX:+HeapDumpAfterFullGC -XX:+HeapDumpBeforeFullGC -XX:HeapDumpPath=. -XX:InitialHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456 -XX:MetaspaceSize=134217728 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC 


'''
2019-10-10T20:26:04.306+0800: 5268.966: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 8192  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2656K(320512K)] 407980K->116148K(1019904K), 0.0037831 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:05.016+0800: 5269.676: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2752512  promoted: 8192  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2688K(320512K)] 407988K->116188K(1019904K), 0.0033875 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:05.709+0800: 5270.368: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 8192  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294528K->2656K(320512K)] 408028K->116164K(1019904K), 0.0034459 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:06.386+0800: 5271.045: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2752512  promoted: 16384  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2688K(320512K)] 408004K->116212K(1019904K), 0.0035608 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:07.074+0800: 5271.734: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 0  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294528K->2656K(320512K)] 408052K->116180K(1019904K), 0.0034802 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:07.741+0800: 5272.401: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 16384  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2656K(320512K)] 408020K->116196K(1019904K), 0.0262302 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:08.476+0800: 5273.136: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 16384  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2656K(320512K)] 408036K->116212K(1019904K), 0.0034859 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:09.180+0800: 5273.840: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2686976  promoted: 0  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2624K(320512K)] 408052K->116180K(1019904K), 0.0034904 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:09.901+0800: 5274.561: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2752512  promoted: 8192  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294464K->2688K(320512K)] 408020K->116252K(1019904K), 0.0037388 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:10.599+0800: 5275.259: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2752512  promoted: 16384  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294528K->2688K(320512K)] 408092K->116268K(1019904K), 0.0035135 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:11.280+0800: 5275.940: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 16384  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294528K->2656K(320512K)] 408108K->116252K(1019904K), 0.0034800 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:11.947+0800: 5276.607: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2719744  promoted: 16384  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2656K(320512K)] 408092K->116268K(1019904K), 0.0291498 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-10-10T20:26:12.619+0800: 5277.279: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 2752512  promoted: 8192  overflow: false
[PSYoungGen: 294496K->2688K(320512K)] 408108K->116308K(1019904K), 0.0033781 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 

'''
```